# DeliveryCount is incresead from message to message in Microsoft Azure ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am using Microsoft Azure Service Bus for .NET Standard.

I'm reading messages from a Service Bus queue using multiple consumers(multiple instances of MessageReceiver) with PeekLock read.

I am not completing the receiving operation for the messages in order for them to be deleted from the queue.

The problem is that the deliveryCount for the second message is basically the deliveryCount for the first message(usually 1) + 1, so 2. Somehow the deliveryCount is passed from one message to another. This problem doesn't occur when I receive both messages with the same receiver(_messageReceiver1 or _messageReceiver2).

msg1 = await _messageReceiver1.ReceiveAsync(80);
Writeline(msg1.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount);

msg2 = await _messageReceiver2.ReceiveAsync(80);
Writeline(msg2.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount);

After exceeding the max delivery count from the portal, because of the delivery count being passed from one message to another, all of my messages are sent to DLQ, even if I was trying to read them or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with [Topic Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions) for multiple consumers. Receiving the messages multiple times will increase the delivery count of the message. Once the count increased more then the Max Delivery Count of the Queue, the messages will be [moved to Dead Letter Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_MaxDeliveryCount).

Comment: The thing is that if I read the second message, its delivery count is already set to 2, and not 1. Somehow the delivery count is passed from one message to another, which is wrong, because the delivery count should be the property of a message.

Comment: There is no way that the delivery count of a message is passed to another. Is there any way that some other receiver might have received the second message.

Comment: No, since I am using the code presented above and without CompleteAsync() the first message is already locked and the first consumer waits the lock time. However, if I close the first consumer before trying to read with the second one, the delivery count for the second message is 1, as normal. Somehow the consumers need to be closed before reading with another consumer.

Comment: I suggest you to use PeekAsync instead of ReceiveAsync, this will not increase the delivery count of the message.

Comment: In that case the messages won't be deleted from the queue, and I want that to be happening at some point.

Comment: Increase the Max Delivery Count to a higher value, doing this will stop the messages from moving to DL Queue

Comment: That would be just a quick fix that won't work with a lot of messages..

Comment: Then you should probably go with Topic Subscriptions as I mention in the answer, which should be used for multiple consumers.